# How can I print feature map image in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, matplotlib, deep-learning

I am a student who is studying deep learning, classification using tensorflow.

I just one question. How can I print a feature map image?

I succeeded convert tensor type data into `numpy.ndarray` type data.

**LIKE THIS** -> **C8: Tensor("C8:0", shape=(0, 7, 7, 0), dtype=float32)** is converted into ndarray.)
[image]

but, I cannot show this feature map.

**First way: using matplotlib.pyplot module**

```py
ep, temp_array, weight_1 = sess.run([tf.argmax(result, 1), c8, wfc1], feed_dict={X: ex, istraining.name: False, keep_prob: 1.0})

print(type(temp_array), temp_array.shape, "\n", temp_array[0, :, :, 0])

img = plt.imread(temp_array[0, :, :, 0])
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

feature map is in temp_array variable. And it(ndarray type) is printed like that image.

I have error message.

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/3Laaaaab/DC/hand_recog_demo_1.py", line 352, in <module>
    img = plt.imread(temp_array[0, :, :, 0])
  File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2152, in imread
    return matplotlib.image.imread(fname, format)
  File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 1369, in imread
    return handler(fname)
TypeError: Object does not appear to be an 8-bit string path or a Python file-like object
```

**Second way: using cv2 module**

```py
ep, temp_array, weight_1 = sess.run([tf.argmax(result, 1), c8, wfc1], feed_dict={X: ex, istraining.name: False, keep_prob: 1.0})

print(type(temp_array), temp_array.shape, "\n", temp_array[0, :, :, 0])

cv2.imshow("windows", temp_array[0, :, :, 0])
cv2.waitKey(1)
```

yes, this source is working well, but I have one problem.

that is, the resulting image is soo small. So I can't see it.

[image]

how can I see the feature map perfectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`plt.imread()` is to read a picture file from the disk (for ex a jpg or png file)](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imread.html?highlight=imread#matplotlib.pyplot.imread).

The error clearly indicates that it is that instruction that raises the error, and that the function expected a path (as a string) or a file-like object, and not an array as you've tried to do.

Since you already have your array in memory, you don't need to use that instruction. It seems like

```
ep, temp_array, weight_1 = sess.run([tf.argmax(result, 1), c8, wfc1], feed_dict={X: ex, istraining.name: False, keep_prob: 1.0})
plt.imshow(temp_array[0, :, :, 0])
plt.show()
```

should be enough?